# Google Analytics / AdWords: No "finalUrl" dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I'm using the Google Analytics API, querying AdWords though an associated GA account.

AdWords seems to have deprecated "Destination URL", replacing it with "Final URL". However, the GA API does not have a dimension for "Final URL"; only "destinationUrl".

It seems like "destinationUrl", queried through GA, provides different statistics to the "Final URL" statistics available on the AdWords dashboard.

So, it this a gap in the API? Am I required to go directly to the AdWords API to achieve what I want? (This would be cumbersome for me, as there's no official AdWords library for Node.js.)

Comment: Yes I think you will need to go though the adwords api.  I am surprised there isn't a node js client library out there to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the AdWords API as it provides more data than the Analytics API.

I had the same issue when I tried to access Search Console data via Analytics. Although Analytics displays various Search Console data in the UI, it is only possible to access this data via Search Console API.